# Zoom to model to fit viewport size

Tags: opengl

I am currently developing applications with model on screen and need to get some way how to zoom to model (make a trick when geometry on screen takes as much place as possible).

My matrices are rather simple. I took `_xrot`, `_yrot` and `_scale` from mouse inputs.

```
    var projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(_viewportSize.Width, _viewportSize.Height, 10000f, -10000f);

    var viewMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationY((float)(_xrot)) *
                     Matrix4.CreateRotationX((float)(_yrot)) *
                     Matrix4.CreateScale((float)_scale);

    var modelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;
```

Then I am multiplying this matrices with coordinates and get my rendered geometry.

Also, I have points of my bounding box (maximum and minimum X, Y and Z). I tried to solve all this by myself, but my efforts failed.

```
    var maxPoint = new Vector3(_maxX, _maxY, _maxZ);
    var minPoint = new Vector3(_minX, _minY, _minZ);

    var pToProject = maxPoint.Length > minPoint.Length ? maxPoint : minPoint; 

    var projectedPoint =
        Vector3.TransformPerspective(pToProject, modelMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix); //transform max point to NDC

    var minP = Math.Min(projectedPoint.X, Math.Min(projectedPoint.Y, projectedPoint.Z));

    _scale = 1/Math.Abs(minP);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. First, I collected all corner points of bounding box, then multiply them with MVP matrix. After it, I divide `1/X` and `1/Y` and looked up to find the minimum proprortion, multiply `_scale` with that value and found new `viewMatrix`.